# Playback pure tone, variable phase stream with pyaudio

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi3, pyaudio

I'm building an acoustic cancelling device based on Pyaudio, fourier transforms and. c-Media usb audio card. The software is threaded, using the producer/consumer model.

The device detects pure tones in the environment (reads chunks of microphone audio), uses fourier to detect the pure tone, and so far so good it works like a charm.

The final step however is getting tricky. I'm aiming to generate a 100ms wave (sine wave), which holds a certain amounts of periods of the frequency to be cancelled.

This wave buffer has to be played with Pyaudio on a separate thread continuously, which also must increase the phase little by little till detecting the amplitude of the tone in the environment drops. This is basically destructive interference.

My problem is when using Pyaudio.stream.write(), the buffer keeps overruning, since i have NO IDEA, what the function is doing internally. I have tried with many combinations of "frame_buffer_size" and audio lenght and no matter what i do, the buffer is overrun.

Ideally, the buffer does not have to be recalculated with a different phase on each run... instead, i'm trying pyaudio to read a different part of the buffer (window) to start writing the sine wave on a different origin each time.

I have no idea how to do that.

Long story short, how would you:

1) create a thread to fill a circular buffer continuously with audio data.
2) create a pyaudio consumer thread that continuously reads the buffer without overruning.
3) manipulate the volume on realtime

My output data must be 44100 hz, little endian, 16bit signed int. Any hints, advise, references or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to be clear, i've already been through all the documentation on Pyaudio and also saw some similar questions on stackoverflow... but none of them seem to use threads to implement stream.write().

Comment: It's hard to say what's going wrong, since you provided no runnable code. Normally, this kind of task can be better tackled with the callback API. Then you wouldn't even have to create a thread in Python, since PortAudio creates one for you.